Unable to foward a sync url to pouchdb using nextjs api's
this is my local.ini couchdb file:
[admins]
admin = <REDACTED>

[couchdb]
database_dir = <REDACTED>
view_index_dir = <REDACTED>
uri_file = <REDACTED>
uuid = <REDACTED>

[cluster]
n = 1
q = 2

[couch_peruser]
enable = true
delete_dbs = true
database_prefix = <REDACTED>

[log]
writer = file
file = <REDACTED>

[chttpd_auth]
secret = <REDACTED>

[chttpd]
enable_cors = true
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, proxy_authentication_handler}

[jwt_keys]
hmac:_default = <REDACTED>
required_claims = exp, sub
roles_claim_path = _couchdb.roles

[cors]
credentials = true
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
origins = *

[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

Issue: Unable to Retrieve Data and Initiate Sync with Backend in Next.js and PouchDB
I'm working on a Next.js project that uses cookies for authentication and sync data with a CouchDB backend via a custom API route. However, I am unable to retrieve data and initiate synchronization properly.
Here's a breakdown of my setup:
Next.js API Route (api/sync)
This API route is responsible for syncing data with the backend (CouchDB).
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export const handler = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  const cookieStore = await cookies();
  const authtoken = cookieStore.get("access_token");
  const database = cookieStore.get("database_name");

  if (!authtoken || !database) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Missing authentication token or database" },
      { status: 400 },
    );
  }

  try {
    const syncResponse = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:5984/${database.value}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authtoken.value}`,
          Referer: "http://localhost:3001",
        },
      },
    );

    if (!syncResponse.ok) {
      const errorDetails = await syncResponse.text();
      console.error(
        `Sync request failed. Status: ${syncResponse.status}, Details: ${errorDetails}`,
      );
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          error: `Sync failed with status ${syncResponse.status}`,
          details: errorDetails,
        },
        { status: syncResponse.status },
      );
    }

    const syncData = await syncResponse.json();
    return NextResponse.json(syncData);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Error forwarding sync request:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
};

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

My thoughts were that if i was able to consume the api in the following way using pouchdb i'd be able to retrieve data and be able sync changes:
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
import PouchDBFind from "pouchdb-find";
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

// Anonymized constants (replace with generic names)
import {
  docType1,
  docType2,
  docType3,
  docType4,
  docType5,
  docType6,
  docType7,
} from "./constants/global.constants";

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);

export const db = <T extends {}>(
  queryClient?: QueryClient,
): PouchDB.Database<T> => {
  let invalidateTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

  // Debounced invalidation function
  const debouncedInvalidateQueries = (queryClient: QueryClient | undefined) => {
    if (invalidateTimeout) clearTimeout(invalidateTimeout);
    invalidateTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      const keys = [
        docType1,
        docType2,
        docType3,
        docType4,
        docType5,
        docType6,
        docType7,
      ];
      keys.forEach((key) =>
        queryClient?.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [key] }),
      );
    }, 500); // Adjust debounce time if necessary
  };

  let wasPaused = false;

  // Use a generic API URL and avoid exposing any sensitive server URLs
  const url = "http://localhost:3001/api/sync/"; // Modify for production or use environment variables
  const opts = { live: true, retry: true };

  // Use a generic database name to hide app details
  const localDb = new PouchDB<T>("generic-local-db", { skip_setup: true });

  try {
    localDb.replicate.from(url).on("complete", function (info) {
      // Two-way, continuous, retriable sync
      localDb
        .sync(url, opts)
        .on("change", (info) => {
          console.log("Sync change:", info);
          debouncedInvalidateQueries(queryClient); // Debounced invalidation
        })
        .on("paused", (err) => {
          if (!wasPaused) {
            console.log("Sync paused:", err);
            if (err) {
              console.error("Sync paused due to error:", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Sync paused, possibly up-to-date.");
            }
            wasPaused = true; // Mark that we are now paused
          }
        })
        .on("active", () => {
          if (wasPaused) {
            console.log("Sync resumed.");
            wasPaused = false; // Mark that we are now active again
          }
        })
        .on("denied", (err) => {
          console.error("Sync denied due to permissions:", err);
        })
        .on("error", (err) => {
          console.error("Error during one-off sync:", err);
        });
    });

    return localDb;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during one-off sync:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

However i get the following logs:
GET /dashboard/items 200 (409ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (368ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (169ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (175ms)
GET /api 404 (235ms)
GET /api 404 (196ms)
GET /api 404 (194ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (97ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (118ms)
GET /api/sync/_changes 404 (184ms)
GET /api/sync 200 (224ms)
GET /api/sync/_changes 404 (211ms)
GET /api/sync/_changes 404 (143ms)

Other solutions that worked are the following:
when i hard code the access token, everything seems to work fine. However, the cookie will be able to be accessible via JavaScript on the browser:
  const remoteDb = new PouchDB<T>(remoteDbUrl, {
    skip_setup: true,
    fetch: function (url, opts) {
      const headers = new Headers(opts?.headers);
      headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`);

      return PouchDB.fetch(url, { ...opts, headers });
    },
  });


You aren't forwarding all necessary requests to CouchDb, you're only making a request to the database root:
`http://127.0.0.1:5984/${database.value}`

Also, you are not exposing the other CouchDb endpoints via your API. That's why you're getting api/sync 200 but /api/sync/_changes 404.
I'd recommend debugging the working setup in order to get an overview about which requests are made to CouchDb during a full PouchDb sync:

Verifying whether the db and a remote checkpoint exists
Checking for differences in the revision tree
Actually querying the data via the _changes

